# ZF3: How to do DB fetchRow() or fetchAll() or fetchCol() or fetchOne() in ZF3?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-framework3

I've used [ZF1 DB adapter](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html), now I'm learning ZF3, but I can't seem to find the equivalent of:

```
$rows = $db->fetchAll('select * from `my_table`');
$row = $db->fetchRow('select * from `my_table` where `id` = 1');
$values = $db->fetchCol('select `my_col` from `my_table`');
$value = $db->fetchOne('select `my_col` from `my_table` where `id` = 1');
```

The examples I found in ZF3 mentioned to use prepare statements. So how to do the above each in 1 line in ZF3?

Comment: You can mimic the behavior by creating a super class or trait that you can push into a desired model to add this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One word: gone. Now you have to deal with `ResultSet\ResultSetInterface` interface instead. But it is an iterator. You surely should not have any trouble getting a result.

Comment: A side note to myself and anyone else looking: By using the `ResultSetInterface`, it has an interesting function to fetch all results, like so: `$result = $adapter->query('SELECT * from users', Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
$users = $result->toArray();`

Answer (score 3):

Yeah it's gone.

You can build the the select on the same way as in ZF1. Example from my code:

```
// From Mapper that extends AbstractTableGateway 
// and implements AdapterAwareInterface

$select = $this->getSql()->select()
        ->join('articles', 'article_events.article_uuid = articles.article_uuid')
        ->where(['articles.article_id' => $id]);

$result = $this->selectWith($select);  

// $result; is fetchAll()
// $result->current();  is fetchRow() or fetchOne() 
// $result->current()->col_name  is fetchCol();
```